# Looking up value in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter, dask

could you help me to solve my problem. I have a csv file with 12000000 lines, I need to search for two values on it and display the third value if it matches. But in the csv file there are values with 14 decimals, and I am searching for a value with 4 decimal places.
This is the working code:

```
df2 = dk.read_csv(filename)
df2.to_parquet('n46_e032_1arc_v3_parquet')
time_start = time.time()
df2 = dk.read_parquet('n46_e032_1arc_v3_parquet') #, sep=',', names=['x', 'y', 'z']
elevation2 = df2[(df2['x'] == 32.001111111111115) & (df2['y'] == 46.99999999999999)].compute()
print(elevation2)
print(time.time() - time_start)
elevation2 = np.asarray(elevation2.z.tolist())
print(elevation2[0])
```

I tried this, but it returns an error.

```
time_start = time.time()
df2 = dk.read_parquet('n46_e032_1arc_v3_parquet') #, sep=',', names=['x', 'y', 'z']
elevation2 = df2[(round(float(df2['x']), 4) == 32.3452) & (round(float(df2['y']), 4) == 46.4567)].compute()
print(elevation2)
print(time.time() - time_start)
elevation2 = np.asarray(elevation2.z.tolist())
print(elevation2[0])
```

I also tried to overwrite the file, but 10 lines are overwritten for one minute, which is very long.

```
filename = 'n46_e032_1arc_v3.csv'
time_start = time.time()
df2 = pd.read_csv(filename)
for i in range(0, 10):
    df2['x'][i] = round(float(df2['x'][i]), 4)
    df2['y'][i] = round(float(df2['y'][i]), 4)
df2 = df2.to_csv("DEM.csv", index=True, header=True)
print(time.time() - time_start)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv3zE.png)

Comment: "it returns an error" : which error ? which line ?
Why do the values differ between the 1st example and the 2nd ?
32.001111111111115 vs 32.3452

Comment: In the first example, I just showed the working code with the value 32.001111111111115 , the value as in the csv file, but I need it to search only 4 decimal places, for example 32.3452.

Comment: Understood. Just it's better to illustrate your issue to use the same values everywhere.

Comment: hanks, I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: Can you try something like that to see if the result differs ? `elevation2 = df2[(32.3452 <= df2['x'] <= 32.3453) & (46.4567 <= df2['y'] <= 46.4568)].compute()`

Comment: Yes thanks, it works like this: elevation2 = df2[(32.0011 <= df2['x']) & (df2['x'] <= 32.0014) & (46.9999 <= df2['y']) & (df2['y'] <= 47.0000)].compute()

Answer (score 0):

The relevant method is `.round`, which will round your pandas series to the desired precision:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'a': [32.001111111111115, 32.3452, 32.345211111]})
mask = df['a'].round(4) == 32.3452
print(df.loc[mask])
```

To be safe, you might want to round the target value also (to avoid problems due to float precision):

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'a': [0.30000000000000004, 0.3001, 0.3002]})
mask = df['a'].round(4) == round(0.1*3, 4)
print(df.loc[mask])
```

Translation to the `dask.dataframe` is very similar:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_csv  # or read_parquet, as necessary
ddf = read_csv(...)
mask = ddf['a'].round(4) == round(0.1*3, 4)
subset_ddf = ddf.loc[mask]
subset_ddf.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: df2 = dk.read_parquet('n46_e032_1arc_v3_parquet')
elevation2 = df2[(df2['x'].round(4) == round(32.0027, 4)) & (df2['y'].round(4) == round(46.9999, 4))].compute()
print(elevation2)
elevation2 = np.asarray(elevation2.z.tolist())
print(elevation2[0])
Can't find value